# gnuplot iteration and autotitle

Tags: gnuplot

I am somewhat new to `gnuplot` [iteration](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/01/plot-iterations-and-pseudo-files.html).  Its a geat feature, but I and trying to find a good way at entering the multiple titles to the plot.

My data is in the form;

```
xdata data1 data2 data3 data4
1 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4
2 0.1 1.1 2.2 3.3
3 4.2 5.2 6.4 3.7
```

If I type

```
set key autotitle columnhead
plot "./mydata.txt" u 1:2 w l
```

then gnuplot prints the graph with the header, great!

But I want to plot all the data on the same graph, so I type

```
plot for [i=2:4] "./mydata.txt" u 1:(column(i)) w l
```

This plots the data but not the title.

Does anyone know a way of getting these features to work together,
or do I have to go back to the old way of typing out every plot explicitly
(i.e)

```
plot "./mydata.txt" u 1:2 w l, \
 "./mydata.txt" u 1:3 w l, \
 "./mydata.txt" u 1:4 w l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out either until by fooling around with the syntax accidentally, this

```
plot for [i=2:4] "./mydata.txt" u 1:i w l
```

is working.
I didn't find any reference to this behavior in the documentation, so this might be a glitch worth reporting...!?

Comment: Good job!  I was hoping you would answer - I think I only found out about the iteration method from one of your previous answers on SO

Comment: @Tom I am glad to be of help^^